# Expand clickable area of an ImageView by using padding?

Tags: android

I have an ImageView, and I want it to be clickable. The image itself is only 32x32 pixels, but I want the clickable region to be larger so it's easier to hit. I was hoping I could set the layout margin values to increase the size of the imageview's clickable area:

```
<ImageView
   layout_width="32dip"
   layout_height="32dip"
   layout_margin="20dip" />
```

That doesn't work, what I could do is just recreate the image resource to have a larger transparent region around it. That's a bit annoying because it's hard to tweak if I ever need to change the clickable region. It's not just a single png either, it's a statelistdrawable so I have to resize 3 different pngs if I ever need to tweak the clickable area.

Anything else I can do?

Thanks

Comment: This solution might work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475350/how-to-set-a-clickable-region-for-an-imageview

Comment: I know this has already been answered, but in these cases you want to use a TouchDelegate: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suggestions (never tried it myself):

1. Create ImageView as large as you want than put image into it without scaling

   ```
   ImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER).
   ```
2. Brute force approach: create new larger png that has original image centered and the rest of it is transparent.

Comment: Ended up going with the brute-force method.

Comment: ImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER) didn't work for me. It scaled it all the up anyways.

Comment: @thekindofme Adding padding will scale the image if you are using android:background instead of android:src on the ImageView.

Comment: Hello from the future.

Answer (score 38):

Use padding. layout margins are used if for inserting space outside the boundary of the view.

for equal padding on all sides

```
  <ImageView
       android:padding="20dip" />
```

or to set the padding on each side

```
<ImageView
     android:paddingLeft="10dip"
     android:paddingRight="15dip"
     android:paddingTop="23dip"
     android:paddingBottom="12dip" />
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: This answer should have been flagged as the correct one!

Answer (score 12):

Instead of resizing the image (Peter Knego's answer) or increasing padding (Saimon's answer) I suggest to set the `minWidth` and `minHeight` attributes in combination with `scaleType="center"`:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minWidth="40dp"
  android:minHeight="40dp"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
```

That makes sure that small images have at least a size of 40x40dp while the image is not up-scaled if it's smaller. If one day the image is going to be replaced with another image larger than `minWidth` and `minHeight` it will not grow larger than 40x40dp as it gets downscaled. Thus a minimum clickable dimension of 40x40dp is always guaranted and the image is always displayed nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Use like below; where width/height is your touch radius

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/editProfile"
  android:layout_width="32dp"
  android:layout_height="32dp"
  android:padding="8dp"
  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
/>
```

In the above code, I wanted my src size to be viewed as 24dp width/height. And touch radius of 32dp. so I had used padding of 8dp.

Comment: Am I mistaken in thinking the height and width should actually be 40 (24+8+8), not 32 (24+8). The 8dp padding that's been added have been added to all sides, so 8*2 dp have been removed from the total height of the icon, not just 8. Same goes for the width.